# Angularjs: how to get "raw" routeParams (without encoding or decoding)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a route like:

```
when('/show_project/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'app/projects/show.html',
}).
```

I have observed that when I request a url like `/show_project/trying%29`, angularjs automatically converts it to `/show_project/trying)`, probably because the character ")" is indeed allowed in urls.

However, I need to get in `$routeParams.name` the original string that was introduced in the url, in this case `trying%29`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ngSanitize:

your module:

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('appsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/show_project/:name', {
        templateUrl: 'app/projects/show.html',
    })
}]);
```

Your Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('appsApp')
.controller('appsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$sanitize', 
  function($scope, $routeParams, $sanitize) {
    var controller = this;

    var name = $routeParams.name;

    $scope.name = $sanitize(name);

}]);
```

NOTE: I just looked and it looks like there is a new official Angular version here:

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize